# How to make function with a few setStates in it synchronous?

Tags: reactjs

I need to make a button click handler which have a few other function calls in it. One of them is a `onAccept` function which has a few setStates in it and want to wait until them all is done. Is there a way to make `onAccept` synchronous?

button click handler

```
const onUpdateBoundaries = async (recommendation) => {
    await getSnippetIndex(
        //some props
    ).then(response => {
      onAccept({...recommendation, index: response});
    });
    
    fetchRecommendations() //<- this function shouldn't be called until onAccept's setStates are done
  };
```

onAccept

```
const onAccept = (recommendation) => {
    setAccepted((accepted) => [
      ...new Set([...accepted, ...recommendation.cluster_indices.map(recommendation => recommendation.index)]),
    ]);
    setRejected((rejected) => [
       ...new Set(removeFromArray(rejected, recommendation.cluster_indices.map(recommendation => recommendation.index)))
    ]);
  };
```

fetchRecommendations

```
const fetchRecommendations = async () => {
    try {
      const {//some props
        propagated_accepted,
        propagated_rejected,
      } = await getRecommendations(
          //some props
      );
      setAccepted((accepted) => [...accepted, ...propagated_accepted]);
      setRejected((rejected) => [...rejected, ...propagated_rejected]);
    } catch (err) {
      //handling
    }
    setIsWaitingForRecommendations(false);
  };
```

Comment: A `useEffect` with the correct dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `useEffect` and `useRef` to achieve it

```
//track all previous values before state updates
const previousValues = useRef({ rejected, accepted });

useEffect(() => {
   //only call `fetchRecommendations` once both `rejected` and `accepted` get updated
   if(previousValues.current.rejected !== rejected && previousValues.current.accepted !== accepted) {
      fetchRecommendations()
   }
}, [rejected, accepted])
```

Another easier way that you can try `setState`, which is the old-school function with callback (the problem with this solution is you need to use **class component** - NOT function component)

```
const onAccept = (recommendation) => {
  setState((prevState) => ({
    accepted: [
      ...new Set([...prevState.accepted, ...recommendation.cluster_indices.map(recommendation => recommendation.index)]),
    ],
    rejected: [
      ...new Set(removeFromArray(prevState.rejected, recommendation.cluster_indices.map(recommendation => recommendation.index)))
    ]
  }), () => {
    //callback here
    fetchRecommendations()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React is declarative, which means it will control the  `setState` function calls incl. batching them if necessary to optimise performance.

What you can do is make use of a `useEffect` to listen for changes in state and run code you need to run after state change there.
For eg: ( I'm assuming your two states are `accepted` and `rejected`)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecommendations() //<- gets called everytime accepted or rejected changes
   }, [accepted, rejected])

// onAccept remains the same

 //button click handler

const onUpdateBoundaries = async (recommendation) => {
 const response = await getSnippetIndex( //some props )
  onAccept({...recommendation, index: response});
};
```

If you want to run it only if current values of `accepted` or `rejected` has changed, you can make use of use Ref to store the previous values of accepted and rejected.

You can create a custom hook like

```
  function usePrevious(value) {
      const ref = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
      });
      return ref.current;
    }
```

Then

```
// import usePrevious hook  
const prevAccepted = usePrevious(accepted)
const prevRejected = usePrevious(rejected)

  useEffect(() => {
       if(prevAccepted!=accepted && prevRejected!=rejected)
        fetchRecommendations() //<- gets called everytime accepted or rejected changes
       }, [accepted, rejected])
    
    const onUpdateBoundaries = async (recommendation) => {
     const response = await getSnippetIndex( //some props )
      onAccept({...recommendation, index: response});
    };
```

Think something like this would do the trick. Let me know if this works :)

Comment: make sense, but what if ```fetchRecommendations``` also changes states of both accepted and rejected, then we got infinite requests. I've edited question and added its code as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a **async method** like this

```js
const SampleOfPromise = () => {
  onClick=async()=>{
    await myPromise();
  }
  
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('sample');
    }, 300);
  });
  return(
     <Button onClick={onClick}>

    </Button>
  )
}
```